# Is there a way to define fprintf in terms of printf / simpler functions (easily)?

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll, printf, mingw

I'm trying to link a program built with MSVC against a DLL compiled with MinGW. The problem is the DLL assumes the function `fprintf` exists, but MSVC doesn't have a definition for it in any of the libraries it links against.  I cannot change versions of neither MSVC nor of MinGW, so the only way I can think around the problem is to write my own `fprintf`, but I would hope there's a simple implementation that doesn't require from me to maintain a whole library of code...

Comment: "MSVC doesn't have a definition for it (`fprintf`)" sounds incorrect.

Comment: @chux what I mean is that MSVC cannot find a binary definition (i.e. a `.data` section with the name `fprintf` in any of the libraries it has available). I think it's quite obvious from the context what I mean though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to define fprintf in terms of printf / simpler functions (easily)?"

Yes, if the library has `vfprintf()`

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int my_own_fprintf(FILE * stream, const char * format, ...) {
  int y;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  y = vfprintf(stream, format, args);
  va_end(args);
  return y;
}
```